# Possible to create a curve + array of collection instances?

Tags: instances, curve-modifier, looping

I'm looking to create a looping background to create the illusion of trees scrolling past the camera. I want the trees to be parented to a circular ground plane (that is controlled by an empty that spins the plane at a set rate), and to save on rendering out hundreds of frames, I'm thinking I can just create an endless loop using 6 trees maximum and loop the end frame to beginning without notice.

I currently have the tree in it's own collection, and I just want to instance this tree onto the ground plane. Because the ground plane is circular, I would like to create a curved path that the instances can adhere to, so they stay in place to make the loop feel seamless.

The issue is, it looks like Blender doesn't allow modifiers on collection instances (the spanner icon is missing when I select a collection instance), but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this anyway, using a different method? I just don't want to have to place the instances by hand, it's really tricky to get their rotation just right.

Comment: You could create a mesh > Circle, in the Object panel > Instancing, enable Vertices, put all the elements of the tree in a collection, create a collection instance and parent it to the circle, the tree will be instanced on each vertex of the circle

Comment: Or use a Geometry nodes tree and an Instance on Points node with your collection as input

Comment: @moonboots clever solution, that worked! Only thing is, there's an instance of the tree  dead center of the circle, and I can't have it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a mesh > *Circle*, in the *Object panel > Instancing*, enable *Vertices* (you can disable *Viewport* and *Render* later), put all the elements of your tree in a collection, create a collection instance and parent it to the circle, the tree will be instanced on each vertex of the circle. To make the collection instance invisibile in preview select it and press <kbd>H</kbd> (it will be invisible in the render anyway).